# Communicate with USB device in C# using LibUsbDotNet

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

0) Working under Windows7 Ultimate 32-bit and installed linusb-win32-dlevel-filter 1.2.6.0.

1) I tried showinfo example of libusb dotnet and got following result,[Please see the result (1-Result)]

2) After that i am trying to read (polling) example of libusb but got error on line "ec = reader.Read(readBuffer, 1000, out bytesRead);" 
and error is "win32error:no more byte!" [Please see code (2-Code) ]

What is this error means and how can i solve it? 
Actually i am new in usb device communication, please help me if have any idea to usb device communication using c#

1-Result:-

Length:18
DescriptorType:Device
BcdUsb:0x0110
Class:Comm
SubClass:0x00
Protocol:0x00
MaxPacketSize0:64
VendorID:0x11CA
ProductID:0x0241
BcdDevice:0x0100
ManufacturerStringIndex:1
ProductStringIndex:2
SerialStringIndex:3
ConfigurationCount:1
ManufacturerString:VeriFone Inc
ProductString:Trident USB Device 1.1
SerialString:

Length:9
DescriptorType:Configuration
TotalLength:67
InterfaceCount:2
ConfigID:1
StringIndex:0
Attributes:0xC0
MaxPower:25
ConfigString:

Length:7
DescriptorType:Endpoint
EndpointID:0x85
Attributes:0x03
MaxPacketSize:16
Interval:0
Refresh:0
SynchAddress:0x00

Length:9
DescriptorType:Interface
InterfaceID:1
AlternateID:0
EndpointCount:2
Class:Data
SubClass:0x00
Protocol:0x00
StringIndex:0
InterfaceString:

Length:7
DescriptorType:Endpoint
EndpointID:0x81
Attributes:0x02
MaxPacketSize:64
Interval:0
Refresh:0
SynchAddress:0x00

Length:7
DescriptorType:Endpoint
EndpointID:0x03
Attributes:0x02
MaxPacketSize:32
Interval:0
Refresh:0
SynchAddress:0x00

2- Code :-

public static UsbDeviceFinder MyUsbFinder = new UsbDeviceFinder(4554, 577);

ErrorCode ec = ErrorCode.None;

```
        try
        {
            // Find and open the usb device.
            MyUsbDevice = UsbDevice.OpenUsbDevice(MyUsbFinder);

            // If the device is open and ready
            if (MyUsbDevice == null) throw new Exception("Device Not Found.");

            IUsbDevice wholeUsbDevice = MyUsbDevice as IUsbDevice;
            if (!ReferenceEquals(wholeUsbDevice, null))
            {
                // This is a "whole" USB device. Before it can be used, 
                // the desired configuration and interface must be selected.

                // Select config #1
                wholeUsbDevice.SetConfiguration(1);

                // Claim interface #0.
                wholeUsbDevice.ClaimInterface(0);
            }

            // open read endpoint 1.
            UsbEndpointReader reader = MyUsbDevice.OpenEndpointReader(ReadEndpointID.Ep01);


            byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1024];
            while (ec == ErrorCode.None)
            {
                int bytesRead;

                // If the device hasn't sent data in the last 5 seconds,
                // a timeout error (ec = IoTimedOut) will occur. 
                ec = reader.Read(readBuffer, 5000, out bytesRead);

                if (bytesRead == 0) throw new Exception(string.Format("{0}:No more bytes!", ec));
                Console.WriteLine("{0} bytes read", bytesRead);

                // Write that output to the console.
                Console.Write(Encoding.Default.GetString(readBuffer, 0, bytesRead));
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\r\nDone!\r\n");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine((ec != ErrorCode.None ? ec + ":" : String.Empty) + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (MyUsbDevice != null)
            {
                if (MyUsbDevice.IsOpen)
                {

                    IUsbDevice wholeUsbDevice = MyUsbDevice as IUsbDevice;
                    if (!ReferenceEquals(wholeUsbDevice, null))
                    {
                        // Release interface #0.
                        wholeUsbDevice.ReleaseInterface(0);
                    }

                    MyUsbDevice.Close();
                }
                MyUsbDevice = null;

                // Free usb resources
                UsbDevice.Exit();

            }

            // Wait for user input..
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

By attention to your descriptor you must set your *interface* as **1**.

```
wholeUsbDevice.ClaimInterface(1)
```